# Rendering Complex Shapefile in Leaflet?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, leaflet, geojson, qgis2web

I'm trying to display a rather complex shapefile in a browser. I'm using QGIS's QGIS2Web plugin. The shapefile is only about 7 mg, but it is made up of about 66,000 line segments, so it isn't rendering properly. What are my options? Is there some way to only render parts of the geojson at lower zoom levels, so the browser doesn't try to render the whole thing?

Comment: You might be able to hack the qgis2web results to include 

https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt

Answer (score 3):

Your best option for the web is mapbox vector tiles format either folder of PBF or MBTILES. Open Layers natively supports vector tiles. Leaflet via plugin.  Use tippecanoe by mapbox or other tools to build it. You could also try geopackage and geopackage-js it uses RTree spatial index. Use QGIS to save your data as gpkg.

Comment: A better solution than mine, though not currently possible withing qgis2web (which my solution is). You can also include vector tiles in Leaflet via plugins (Leaflet.VectorGrid, I think?).

Comment: Thanks guys. I looked into vector tiles, but I need the user to be able to click on the layer and see information from the attribute table in a pop-up. I was under the impression that you cannot interact with vector tiles?

Comment: You can interact and do popups and even attribute table

Comment: How do you interact with the attribute table of a vector tile? I have uploaded the dataset as a geojson to mapbox studio and converted it to a vector tileset, but now it appears that it is embedded in the basemap - I can't figure out a way to enable clicking on the layer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to host the data somewhere and serve it as a WFS via Geoserver or an equivalent. The "Precision" field in qgis2web could help a little, but it's the number of lines that is the issue, not the size of the data.